# npm gives error when installing module not specified by me

Tags: node.js, npm, gulp

I am trying to install the modules needed by my application using

```
npm install
```

When I do this, I get the following error:

```
npm ERR! Error: No compatible version found: gulp-util@'^3.0.0'
npm ERR! Valid install targets:
npm ERR! ["0.0.1","1.0.0","1.1.0","1.1.1","1.2.0","1.3.0","2.0.0","2.1.1","2.1.2","2.1.3","2.1.4","2.2.0","2.2.1","2.2.2","2.2.3","2.2.5","2.2.6","2.2.7","2.2.8","2.2.9","2.
2.10","2.2.11","2.2.12","2.2.13","2.2.14","2.2.15","2.2.16","2.2.17","2.2.18","2.2.19","2.2.20","3.0.0","3.0.1","3.0.2","3.0.3","3.0.4","3.0.5","3.0.6"]
```

However, I never require this module into my project.
I'm assuming it's an issue internal of npm or node.

Furthermore, also strange is that when I run

```
npm list -g
```

I get the following output rather than seeing the versions of npm which are installed.

```
├── node@0.0.0
```

My `package.json` file is:

```
{
  "name": "myProject",
  "version": "0.0.1",
  "dependencies": {},
  "scripts": {
    "test": "gulp test"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "browserify": ">=9.0.7",
    "gulp": ">=3.8.11",
    "gulp-concat": ">=2.6.0",
    "gulp-html-replace": ">=1.5.1",
    "gulp-react": ">=3.0.1",
    "gulp-streamify": ">=1.0.2",
    "gulp-uglify": ">=1.2.0",
    "gulp-util": ">=3.0.6",
    "reactify": ">=1.1.1",
    "vinyl-source-stream": ">=1.1.0"
  },
  "engines": {
    "node": ">=0.10.0"
  }
}
```

Comment: Could you please provide your `package.json`

Comment: I just tested that locally and all packages install fine for me. Can you run `npm --version` and `node --version` please

Comment: npm is `1.1.69`, node is `v0.8.16`

Comment: Did updating your version of npm solve this for you?

Answer (score 1):

Your version of npm is so old that it doesn't support version ranges specified using `^`. You are not using that syntax but it is quite likely one of the modules you are specifying is using that syntax for it's dependencies, and so when it tries to run `npm install gulp-util@'^3.0.0'` it throws that error.

If you update your npm either by updating node or by installing the latest npm with `npm install -g npm` then you should be able to proceed.